# How to skip steps if imacros found a specific text?

Tags: javascript, firefox, imacros

Hi and happy new year all,

I'm testing a website using imacros plugin for firefox.

My problem is :
On certain webpages, there is no data, juste a text :
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:No information

I would like to skip steps if I found this, is it possible ?

For information, I tried :

```
'Test
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:ATTR=TXT:No<SP>information
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var text=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; if(text!=\"No<SP>information\"){
my code
})"
```

Without succes :(

EDIT : I thing, the best way would  be to put an if statement like that :

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:No<SP>information EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; if (s ==\"No<SP>information\") else SET !TIMEOUT_TAG 0" )
```

But this syntax returns a 910 error code

EDIT 2 : 
I took another way and I created a JS file but now, i'm blocked on a simple task (click on a tag^^)

This is my new code :

```js
var macro;
var start;

for(var i = 1; i <11; i++)
{
macro = "CODE:";
macro += "VERSION BUILD=8940826 RECORDER=FX" + "\n";
macro += "TAB T=1" + "\n";
macro += "SET !TIMEOUT_TAG 10" + "\n";
macro += "SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO" + "\n";
macro += "'SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
macro += "TAG  XPATH=\"(.//span/center/a)[" + i + "]\"" + "\n";
macro += "WAIT SECONDS=2" + "\n";

macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:More<SP>informations<SP>+" + "\n";


start = iimPlay(macro);  
}
```

Now, Imacros don't click on the TAG "More informations+". It ws working using a simple macro.

Comment: It's possible by means of [the JavaScript Scripting Interface for Firefox plugin](http://wiki.imacros.net/Firefox#Javascript_Scripting_Interface)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Shugar.
But I still don't succed to call javascript using EVAL :/